# How to get assign return type from function generic

Tags: typescript

```
class Dyn {
    static flatten (a: any) {

    }
    static cliff <G extends any[], B, A extends (...a: G) => B, Z>(a: A, b: ( ) => Z) {
        return (...p: G) => { 
            const runA = a(...p)
            return {
                _: runA,
                ...b()
            }
        }
    }
}

type User = { name: string, id: number }
type Kitten = { name: string, id: number }
const getUserById = (id: number): User => ({ name: 'thomas', id })
const getKittenById = (id: number): Kitten => ({ name: 'thomas', id})


const x = Dyn.flatten({
    user: Dyn.cliff(getUserById, () => ({
        kitten: getKittenById
    }))
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=5#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCeA7aBvAsAKGt6EAuYeAlsNAGbh54CmyAFGAFzRiLwCUqmmO0Avjxz5CJaKCJky0ADwBxaNQAeNRABMYreAG0AugBpoAIQMBBBctrrodAHR2m0WZwC8APiMGAWq4bMTBgCNmOmgXd09OdCxeHAAnajwAV1j6OxsAB2YnaDdUaEEYmOAAe0R8aFjExDNnFls7dPYCwriE5OQolq7oAH1mSuq9Zu6cNIC6JuiRgSmYmd4Zmcw8eHTqaABVCGpYnLzEMABbamZ8WKJEAHMDIlVmRETDgJ3%20ZdX1gGkiKlo9lGgDsdTnhzlcbncAY9nrsZiUynhoJcElsdoZ4ABJVR7Oi3e5QnbsZgo3a5Oj-QEnaAAcjwAAtiodIFTwfxJnDyki8F8fog0ZjsbjIU8CcxuSocu4yQCjpSafTGRBmdBbnxJtwMOyEYo9ghEDYKIQVGTmoltrFmLqbOJJHROcS%20aoDBMJdZOi0ANbfFTMTli2gO5qqyaqzBAA)

I am trying to understand why when I hover over `Dyn.cliff`.

```
(method) Dyn.cliff<any[], unknown, (id: number) => User, {
    kitten: (id: number) => Kitten;
}>(a: (id: number) => User, b: () => {
    kitten: (id: number) => Kitten;
}): (...p: any[]) => {
    _: unknown;
} & {
    kitten: (id: number) => Kitten;
}
```

How can I have it so that `_: unknown;` us `_: User`?

Comment: What purpose does `A` serve?  Why not just `cliff<G extends any[], B, Z>(a: (...a: G) => B, b: () => Z)`?  Removing indirection layers often improves type inference, I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jcalz mentions in the comments, removing extra type parameters can provide better inference. In this case, you need to remove the extra type parameters and use the `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` helpers to get the desired type. [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=3#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCeA7aBvAsAKGt6EAuYeAlsNAGbh54CmyAFGAFzRiLwCUqmmO0Avjxz5CJaKCJkyAHgCC0agA8aiACYw6AOi1MWbANoBdTgF4AfLvgAaaAC1TDZjOsAjZnWgnzNzuiy8cAE7UeACuAfRaGgAOzAAKYAFgALbB1AEQsqaeXH7+-gD0+dAA6kR4ABYA9iF40BXU8gpRICRldfBRDSrUoAkilcjlaQ0BIYhyRDDdNAFJRIjUKnWV0M4NAAas8OuCebyFq9RklUF1Q9AA5rRpopPQQRCVIABuixq7e9jAA-j3YzLMABKwTCiAAKh1qJloMYWJotFF2B9PkFQuEcp9PgB9ZijcaWZGY7CRZx0JG5TECCm8Kk0zBUzB4SHQACqEDSMNQ0EQyWozHwAXmF2sRBUzEQISSawC-EZzIA0mVlJyUNzefy8ILEMLoKLxZLpbKMN9EL8rng2WkAELwACSS1hdD13INaXYzEtMrM0Doqp5KWYAHIKpUkpBAyKlnxySazcFFVRaDb7ZynWKXVK3cwE8rvb61QHoMGqmGIBHdSpo9wMJhY7UFJyEIgNBRCMpfR8QuyAswmxpxJI6ObPcmVNYyTDzB3qTgANZK2jMc05pN2lQfaPk6NAA).

```
class Dyn {
    static flatten (a: any) {

    }
    static cliff<A extends (...a: any[]) => any, Z>(a: A, b: ( ) => Z) {
        return (...p: Parameters<A>) => {
            // Without the explicit type declaration here runA is determined to be `any`
            // before the generic is resolved.
            const runA: ReturnType<A> = a(...p)
            return {
                _: runA,
                ...b()
            }
        }
    }
}

type User = { name: string, id: number }
type Kitten = { name: string, id: number }
const getUserById = (id: number): User => ({ name: 'thomas', id })
const getKittenById = (id: number): Kitten => ({ name: 'thomas', id})


const x = Dyn.flatten({
    user: Dyn.cliff(getUserById, () => ({
        kitten: getKittenById
    }))
})
```